# How to get an Absolute Path from a URI in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, uri

I've been trying to convert a  folder URI path from *DocumentPicker* to an absolute path, but to no avail :

```
const handleSelectLocation = async () => {
    try {
      const {uri} = await DocumentPicker.pickDirectory({
        type: [DocumentPicker.types.allFiles],
      });

      setFolderUri(uri);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Document Picker Error:', error);
    }
  };
```

This results in a path like :

`content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADocuments`

Then I try retrieving an absolute path from the URI :

```
await getFileAbsolutePath(folderUri);

export const getFileAbsolutePath = async uri => {
  let retVal = null;

  try {
    let fileStats = await RNFetchBlob.fs.stat(uri);
    retVal = fileStats.path;
  } catch (error) {
    retVal = null;
  }

  return retVal;
};
```

`getFileAbsolutePath` throws the error :

`[Error: failed to stat path` null `because it does not exist or it is not a folder]`

How can I get an *Absolute Path* from a folder URI?

Thank you all in advance.

The above implementation is with `import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob'`.

`npm i react-native-fetch-blob` just won't install into my project.

Comment: what kind of paths are expecting, can you give an example? because this is how the files paths are in android. like the one you provided.